# Dropdown onchange event within an iframe not working

Tags: javascript, iframe

For a variety of complicated reasons I have a Joomla page with an iFrame in it. The page that the iframe calls is classic asp, and the dropdown on there looks like this:

```
<select name="pulldown" onchange="nav_pulldown(this)">
<option value="?wherearewe=here">I want to go here</option>
<option value="?wherearewe=there">I want to go there</option>
</select>
```

The JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<!-- //
function nav_pulldown(list) {
if (list.options[list.selectedIndex].value != "#"); {
top.document.location = list.options[list.selectedIndex].value;
}}
//-->
</script>
```

So, user changes the dropdown menu and the javascript submits the form. The asp page grabs that querystring and renders something or other depending on what was selected. This all works fine when the page is rendered by itself outside of the iframe (when top.document is valid). But I can't determine the proper name or call to have the dropdown target and populate itself onchange. I've tried a bunch of different things.

I have control over both pages, the Joomla and the ASP. For a variety of reasons the querystrings cannot change. The iframe's name is currently formframe, if it matters.

Comment: is the script on the asp page or the iframe?

Comment: The script is on the asp page.

Comment: Put it in the iframe. That should do it.

Comment: won't work as-is in an iframe -- you'll have to change "top.document.location" to "self.location"

Comment: "put it in the iframe" 
That is not an option.

Comment: I am not sure if this is gonna work but you can try `parent.nav_pulldown(this)`

Comment: you'll have to change "top.document.location" to "self.location"

Winner winner chicken dinner! I really thought I'd tried every variation of names and element and whatnot, but no. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As per comments, you need to use `self.location` (or the slightly redundant, but equivalent `self.document.location`) rather than `top.document.location`.

`self` refers to the document where the javascript code resides.  `top` will refer to the top-most parent document.  So when you're not iframing a page, `top` refers to `self`.  But when you are iframing a page, `top` refers to the top-most parent document.